# Rounding up DATEDIFF, TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried using CEILING to round up a DATEDIFF value but still got zero:

```
SELECT (CEILING(DATEDIFF(DAY, '2016-04-02T04:59:59', '2016-04-02T05:59:59')))
```

Is it possible to round up DATEDIFF?

Comment: If you want things that happen on the same day to equal 1 and not zero then it might be easier to get the hours difference and div by 24 then round that up.

Comment: You obatin zero  because the diff in day is  zero

Comment: What should it return if it's the exact same time?

Answer (score 1):

`DATEDIFF()` returns `0` when using `day` if the two dates are the same day. You need to use a smaller time increment and divide the result of the `DATEDIFF()`, Hour and 24, Minute and 1440, Second and 86,400, etc:

```
SELECT CEILING(DATEDIFF(Second, '2016-04-02T04:59:59', '2016-04-02T05:59:59')/(24.0*60*60))
```

Note: Divide the `DATEDIFF()` result by a decimal value otherwise it will return an integer.